# Can't view wifi signal strength with iwconfig or wavemon

Tags: 12.04, wireless, gnome, networking

I have been reading everywhere that I should be able to view wifi signal strength using iwconfig or wavemon but I am not getting that information when I use either of them. I can connect to wifi, and the signal strength icon with the bars in gnome3 works fine, but I want more specific information.

Here is what happens when I use iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"WIFI_ROUTER"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 82:0C:E5:2V:7E:48   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

When using wavemon I get mostly the same info but in the Levels area, it says NO INTERFACE DATA. I assume this is where I should be able to view the signal strength.

What can I do to make the signal strength show up?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like I needed to sudo those commands, works now with sudo iwconfig or sudo wavemon

Comment: Don't forget to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer once you're able to. That way, people searching for a similar issue can easily see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sudo`. In case of `iwconfig` you can do `sudo watch -n 1 iwconfig` to see all the details every second. You will see an output like [image: this]

In case of wavemon do `sudo wavemon` and the output will be like.[image]