# cannot access wifi with wavemon but can with iwconfig

Tags: networking, wireless

TL;DR: `wavemon` does not work, `iwconfig` works fine.

---

## problem

I don't seem to get any results from `wavemon`, although it sees the right interface.

If I start wavemon

```
$ sudo wavemon
```

it shows for `Interface`:

```
wlan0 (IEEE 802.11bgn), phy 0, reg: n/a
```

After the dynamic info update interval, it adds some info on WPA/WPA2:

```
wlan0 (IEEE 802.11bgn, WPA/WPA2), phy 0, reg: n/a
```

Also, it sees my `Network`: `wlan0 (UP RUNNING BROADCAST MULTICAST)`, mac address, qlen (1000), ip and mtu.

However, in the `Levels` panel, it just says

```
NO INTERFACE DATA
```

The `Scan window` (`F3`) says:

```
Scan trigger failed on wlan0: No such device
```

And I have no statistics.

## research

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/304338/448034), but it does not solve my problem for two reasons: 1) I already started wavemon as sudo and 2) I can use `iwconfig` just fine. It says:

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0
[sudo] password for mk:
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"<my essid>"  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 01:23:45:67:89:ab
          Bit Rate:72 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=97/100  Signal level=61/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

(ESSID and Access Point censored)

I also read under Dependencies on [the github source page README.md](https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon) something about `CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT`. However, I read somewhere else that also `iwconfig` should depend on this. Therefore, I expect it is no solution for me.

## info

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with LXDE and use wavemon 0.8.0 with ncurses 6.0.20160213. The USB WLAN adapter is a `0bda:8172` Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n (taken from `lsusb`). Its configuration (from `sudo lshw -class network`) is `broadcast=yes driver=r8712u ip=192.168.2.100 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn`

After installing wavemon, I have rebooted the system.

From `dmesg | grep -i firmware` I read one related line:

```
[   16.880896] usb 1-5: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
```

The network is managed by NetworkManager v1.2.6.

Happy to provide more info where needed (but where to start?)

---

*What I would ultimately want, is diagnose my situation where WiFi is sometimes fast (at least, reasonable as expected, topping at 10Mb/s) and sometimes VERY slow, often reconnecting. I am two floors up (with one layer of enforced concrete) from the router, a WRT160NL, sending wireless-N only. The antennae are pointer sideways to maximize throughput, as is the antenna of the adapter. I expect the distance to be a possible cause, although iwconfig and `/proc/net/wireless` usually report a link quality of 90-100/100 and a signal level of ~70/100. I'd like to look into this a bit further.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `iw dev wlan0 scan` produce any result?  If not then it seems your driver does not support the new wireless networking API.  Try an older version of wavemon v0.7.6

https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon/issues/13

Comment: Installing an older version from [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/wavemon) (the one from Ubuntu 14.04) actually worked. Wavemon is now running as expected.